# Get-AzureADUser with 2 filters?

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

How can I filter Get-AzureADUser for two values?

So for the following I can search for DisplayName starts with Student but I also want to return values where UserPrincipalName also contains "@somedomain.com"

```
Get-AzureADUser -Filter "startswith(DisplayName,'student')"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this can be done with `-Filter` only. Since the oData v3 filters don't support operators (using `match` or `like`) that do partial matching, you have to rely on built-in functions. It appears you can't use the `endswith()` or `substringof()` function in `-Filter`. You'd need to resort to `Where-Object` to filter further.

```
Get-AzureADUser -Filter "startswith(DisplayName,'student')" -All:$true |
    Where UserPrincipalName -like '*@somedomain.com'
```

---

I tested multiple scenarios using the Azure Cloud shell.

```
# Error
Get-AzureADUser -Filter "startswith(displayname,'student') and endswith(displayname,'student')"

# Error
Get-AzureADUser -Filter "startswith(displayname,'student') and endswith(UserPrincipalName,'@domain.com')"

# Error
Get-AzureADUser -Filter "(startswith(displayname,'student')) and (endswith(UserPrincipalName,'@domain.com'))"

# Error
Get-AzureADUser -Filter "endswith(UserPrincipalName,'@domain.com')"

# Error
Get-AzureADUser -Filter "substringof('@domain.com',UserPrincipalName)"

# No Errors
Get-AzureADUser -Filter "startswith(displayname,'student') and startswith(UserPrincipalName,'student')"
```